# SSRS Dynamic Background Color based on data in Dynamic columns

Tags: reporting-services, colors, expression

I have a report with two columns.  These two columns are named either "This Month" or "Last Month".  I am trying to add a background color to the data cells in "This Month" in relation to the data in "Last Month".

I am familiar with dynamic color coding using an IIF statement, but cannot seem to figure this out.

Below, I am trying to use an IIF with a LOOKUP command, but I am not sure if I am even using this command correctly.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
=IIF(LOOKUP(Fields!Type.Value = "This Month", Fields!Type.Value, Fields!Count.Value, "ExecutiveFCAPS") < LOOKUP(
Fields!Type.Value = "Last Month", Fields!Type.Value, Fields!Count.Value, "ExecutiveFCAPS"), "LightGreen", 

IIF(LOOKUP(Fields!Type.Value = "This Month", Fields!Type.Value, Fields!Count.Value, "ExecutiveFCAPS") = LOOKUP(
Fields!Type.Value = "Last Month", Fields!Type.Value, Fields!Count.Value, "ExecutiveFCAPS"), "Yellow", 

IIF(LOOKUP(Fields!Type.Value = "This Month", Fields!Type.Value, Fields!Count.Value, "ExecutiveFCAPS") > LOOKUP(
Fields!Type.Value = "Last Month", Fields!Type.Value, Fields!Count.Value, "ExecutiveFCAPS"), "Orange", "Transparent")))
```

Comment: How many datasets do you have? If one is it bound to the columns (ie tablix)? What fields in the datasets. Please edit your question put this info in. Thanks

Comment: This level of complexity is usually best resolved in your Datasets e.g. using SQL.  That gives you an opportunity to debug and test your code.

Comment: @PreetSangha, Fields are FCAPSSubType, Type (This contains either the This Month or Last Month), Count.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you'll need to do a few things if I'm understanding your issue:

1. Change you `lookup` functions to `lookupset` functions;
2. Replace the `field = "Month"` with the `"Month"` alone, as this will result in only a boolean not the month being looked up; and
3. Wrap them in `sum` functions.

I'd strongly suggest you go back to the sql and re-jig it to produce 2 separate fields, one for `This Month` and another for `Last Month` then you can get rid of the `lookup` functions altogether.

If this doesn't work a suggest you tweak the feeding sql to have a colour for each months value as you can utilise window clauses.

Additionally you could try the `scope` function in ssrs. A good resource to help understand is [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/0bde66d7-b0e4-40da-9a0c-838663e66119).

Comment: I do believe you understand what I am trying to do.  I changed lookup to lookupset and wrapped each lookupset in sum (e.g. =IIF(SUM(LOOKUPSET(FIELD...)  The color of all of the cells was No color.  I tried changing it back to lookup instead of lookupset, and all the cells went yellow.

Comment: This Month and Last Month, are not the only values in the type column.  The values that are in these columns can change.

Comment: I think on that basis you only option is the scope function. This is widely seen issue with the matrix type reports.

Comment: Try removing field="This Month" this will cause a 1 or 0 to be prooduced, I'll update my answer.

Comment: If my understanding is correct, the InScope just checks if the data is there?  I am trying to do a comparison of the data in 1 column against the data in the other.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing all the calculations in SQL, and added a variation column to my dataset.  Within SSRS, I configured my color code to read the variation column, and color code accordingly.  I used CASE to set the variation column data.

=IIF(Fields!Variation.Value = 2, "LightGreen", IIF(Fields!Variation.Value = 3, "Transparent" ,IIF(Fields!Variation.Value = 1, "Orange", "Transparent")))